# How can I reset WiFi without rebooting the phone?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, connection-issues

Sometimes WiFi networks are not picked up on my Moto G. Switching WiFi or flight mode on and off does not solve the problem, however a phone reboot does.

Does anybody know of a way I can reset the WiFi completely without rebooting the phone?

For example, with 3G issues I would go to the testing menu (*#*#4636#*#*) and switch the radio on and off, or switch flight mode on and off, which would typically cure the problem. Anything similar for WiFi? Thank you.

Comment: Is it rooted? You could flash a newer / different radio. Have you tried any wifi fixer applications from the play store? Has this always happened or just started? Have you done anything with the device lately: updated firmware, rooted, flashed a rom or mod, dropped it?

Comment: This phone is not rooted and has the standard 4.4.2 software. This is an issue that has started with a particular network after working fine a few days. I have only updated things like Chrome, Chrome beta & the Google music player. I have not tried WiFi fixer apps, any recommendations?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know which are good. I'd say try something highly rated in the store. It's worth a shot. Is it a specific network, or ALL WiFi? There could be a compatability issue with the router, or just a dodgy internet connection. It's hard to narrow down.

Comment: There's an option in WiFi settings that makes Android ignore networks with weak signal.  You may want yo confirm this option is off.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Backup & reset > Network settings reset

It will reset the WiFi, but it will also delete your APNs and all your WiFi passwords. So, be careful.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This feature was not introduced until Android Lollipop (5.0), previous Android versions did not have a Network Settings Reset option, as the OP stated, this question is specific to Android KitKat, which does not have this option. (Just noticed this question was from 3 years ago... Will remove down vote but leave comment)